# Linkurious will not connect to neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have just downloaded Linkurious v1.2.7 on Windows 7
Neo4j is v2.2.0-M02 running on the same localhost.

Neo4j works without issue.  I have a .NET WebService project that can query the HTTP endpoint at http://localhost:7474/db/data without problem.

Linkurious is installed correctly (presumably).  I have modified the graphdb.json file with the localhost url and username and password for Neo4j.

after some troubleshooting Linkurious can see that the Neo4j database is running but it throws the error:

> "The graph database Rest API did not respond. Please check its connection settings & log trace."

I am not seeing any activity from linkurious in the neo4j console.log.

Anyone have any leads for me? I was hoping to work through the weekend to get this project done.

Comment: I don't know if Linkurious support Neo4j2.2 already. As 2.2 is not in a stable realease yet and the authentication system has been added in 2.2.

Comment: that was it.  I have rolled back to neo4j 2.1.7 and connected with no problem.  I have been using 2.2.0 for so long I forgot it is for "development" only still.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

as Christophe Willemsen indicated, Linkurious 1.2.7 does not yet work with Neo4j 2.2.0.

Answer (score -1):

You can now access a new version called Linkurious Starter that fully supports Neo4j 2.2.0. Go to https://linkurio.us/my-account/ to download it.

Let me know if it solves your issue!